# Using an Array list to dictate the index of another Array list

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList <SlotMachine> machines = new ArrayList<SlotMachine>();
    System.out.print("How many machines are they playing?: ");
    int machinesNeeded = scan.nextInt();
    int machineCounter = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < machinesNeeded; i++) {
        machines.add(new SlotMachine());
        System.out.print("How often does machine # " + machineCounter + " pay its jackpot?: ");
        machines.get(i).setPayOutTime(scan.nextInt());
        System.out.print("How much is the jackpot for machine # " + machineCounter + ": ");
        machines.get(i).setPayOut(scan.nextInt());
        System.out.print("How many times has machine # " + machineCounter + " been played since paying out?: ");
        machines.get(i).setTimesPlayed(scan.nextInt());
        machineCounter ++;
    }

    ArrayList <Integer> machineOrder = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    machineOrder.add(3);
    System.out.print("Enter machine to use: ");
    System.out.println(machines.get(machineOrder.get(0)));
```

I want to use the values in the `machineOrder` list variable as an index to access machines value.
Not sure what to do i keep getting the

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
```

Comment: Remember that you need 4 machines for there to be a machine 3.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are adding 3 items to `machines` and then asking for the item at index 3. If that's the case then the error is telling you that there is no item at index 3 - the indices run from 0 to 2.

Comment: Are your print statements within some method?

Comment: The Integer added in the machineOrder should be less than the machinesNeeded. Otherwise it will throw Array IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a flaw in your code, you are adding machine.add(3), therefore your machine.get(0) always returns 3, you would have added 3 machines as array index start from 0 max index possible is 2, and you are trying to access 3rd element hence you are getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException